# Issue taking active element from a dropdown list using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

As I said in the question, I'm having a hard time taking the active element in a drop down list.

This is my code:

```
saveButton.onclick = function btnSubmitOnClick(e) {
  console.log('saveBtn clicked');
  var user = {
    username: username.innerHTML,
    mood: mood.value,
    status: strUser
  };
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.open('POST', '/profile');
  r.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  r.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
  console.log(user);
  r.send(JSON.stringify(user));
};
```

So, when I run it, after the request is sent all I receive is the username, the status and an empty string for the dropdown menu, no matter what I selected.
But, if I take the code I use to select the active option in the drop down and put it into the browser console (for instance, this):

```
var e = document.getElementById("statusSelect");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
strUser;
```

Then, what I get is the right value like "ready to draw", "online", etc.

Update:
In case you wanted to see it, this is the menu's HTML code (I think I have no issues with it though)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <select id="statusSelect">
            <option value="" disabled selected>{user.status}</option>
            <option value="online">online</option>
            <option value="ready to draw">ready to draw</option>
            <option value="away">away</option>
            <option value="busy">busy</option>
            <option value="offline">offline</option>
          </select>
          <label>Status:</label>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I had to move these 2 variables into the button code

```
var e = document.getElementById("statusSelect");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

So that when I submit I take the current value of the selected in the drop down menu.
Leaving the variables outside (globals) as I did before, I got the initial value which was unselected in the menu and so an empty string.